# Javascript file not executing in Sinatra application

Tags: javascript, ruby, sinatra, haml

App.rb

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
    haml :home
end
```

Home.haml

```
!!!
%html
%head
  %title My app
%body
  .wrapper
%script(src="js/app.js")
```

Folder structure:

```
/myapp/app.rb
/myapp/views/home.haml
/myapp/public/js/myapp.js
```

The template seems to load the javascript file:

[image: firebug]

However it does not execute. The javascript draws a HTML5 canvas and appends it to the wrapper div.
If I type in the URL "localhost:4567/js/myapp.js" the script is shown, so I'm assuming Sinatra is correctly serving it up, however it's not executing.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, I forgot to add jQuery script, so my script wasn't loading because I was using the $(document).ready functionality.